# How can i select data from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, union-all

I selected two different data from same tables but i need this two different datas merge to one table as select.

**For example i have this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT db.nazev, db.skupina, db.datum_od1, db.datum_do1, db.mnozstvi, db.cena_bez_dph, db.datum_od, db.datum_do2, db.mnozstvi2, db.cena_bez_dph2 
FROM (
SELECT s.nazev as nazev, s.kod as skupina, (select (DATE '<<datum_od1>>')) as datum_od1, (select (DATE '<<datum_do1>>')) as datum_do1,  sum(f.mnozmj) as mnozstvi, sum(f.sumZkl) as cena_bez_dph FROM dpolfak as f
LEFT OUTER JOIN ddoklfak hla ON hla.iddoklfak = f.iddoklfak
LEFT OUTER JOIN ccenik c ON c.kod = f.kod
LEFT OUTER JOIN cskupzboz s ON s.idskupzboz = c.idskupzboz
where f.modul = 'FAV' and f.datvyst >= '<<datum_od1>>' and f.datvyst <= '<<datum_do1>>'
GROUP BY s.nazev, s.kod
UNION ALL
SELECT s.nazev as nazev, s.kod as skupina, (select (DATE '<<datum_od2>>')) as datum_od2, (select (DATE '<<datum_do2>>')) as datum_do2,  sum(f.mnozmj) as mnozstvi2, sum(f.sumZkl) as cena_bez_dph2 FROM dpolfak as f
LEFT OUTER JOIN ddoklfak hla ON hla.iddoklfak = f.iddoklfak
LEFT OUTER JOIN ccenik c ON c.kod = f.kod
LEFT OUTER JOIN cskupzboz s ON s.idskupzboz = c.idskupzboz
where f.modul = 'FAV' and f.datvyst >= '<<datum_od2>>' and f.datvyst <= '<<datum_do2>>'
GROUP BY s.nazev, s.kod
) db
```

But problem is that fuction "UNION ALL" merge all data to one so but i need select diferent data from table two into new columns which can you see that in main select.

Main problem is that this dont work **"db.datum_do2, db.mnozstvi2, db.cena_bez_dph2"** with function union all (it still write me that column doesnt exists). How can i fix it?

**This is my actually result:**

```
nazev                   skupina   Datum       Datum        Množství Cena bez DPH
Směsi éterických olejů | SL024 | 01.12.2014 | 19.12.2014 | 1 798,00 | 208 142,79

Směsi éterických olejů | SL024 | 20.11.2014 | 07.01.2015 | 662,00   | 86 374,52
```

and i want this:

```
nazev                   skupina   Datum       Datum        Množství Cena bez DPH  Datum 2      Datum 2       Množství 2  Cena bez DPH 2
Směsi éterických olejů | SL024 | 01.12.2014 | 19.12.2014 | 1 798,00 | 208 142,79 |20.11.2014 | 07.01.2015 | 662,00   | 86 374,52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the UNION ALL's different queries' columns separated, you can either do something like this:

```
select col1, case when q = 1 then colA end, case when q = 2 then colA end,...
(select col1, colA as colA, 1 as q
 from...
 union all
 select col1, colB as colA, 2 as q
 from...
) db
```

or

```
select col1, col2 etc
(select col1, colA, null from...
 UNIOM ALL
 select col1, null, colB from...)
```

Comment: When i try your second variant so it still write me this ""db.datum_do2, db.mnozstvi2, db.cena_bez_dph2" (it still write me that column doesnt exists)."

Comment: Name the column in the UNION's first select.